# If a button is disabled then i want to skip clicking it, and if its enabled i want to click in using cypress

Tags: button, pagination, click, conditional-statements, cypress

I tried below code but its still trying to click the button even if its disabled and the test is getting failed.

```
cy.get('button').should('not.be.disabled').click()<br>
cy.get('button').should('be.enabled').click()
```

Comment: Hey @ashmax, can you check if this works for you `cy.get('button').then(($btn) => {
    if ($btn.is(":disabled")) {
        return
    }
    else {
        cy.wrap($btn).click()
    }
})`

Comment: Can you please share the failure?

Comment: @AlapanDas your code works thankyou :)

Comment: @ashmax Happy to help. I have added this as an answer, so it can help others as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery disabled-selector](https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) to achieve this. Your code should look like:

```
cy.get('button').then(($btn) => {
  if ($btn.is(":disabled")) {
    return
  } else {
    cy.wrap($btn).click()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5):

I suggest [invoke attribute](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke.html#Rules):

```
cy.get('button')
    .invoke('attr', 'disabled')
    .then(disabled =>{
        disabled ? cy.log('buttonIsDiabled') : cy.get('button').click()
    })
```